# Logistical Regression issue

Tags: r, regression, logistic-regression

I'm having some issues running glm in r for my dataset. The dataset looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMt9h.png)

C_SEV is the severity of the crash: 0 is non-fatal / 1 is fatal

I've created a new column to set C_SEV as binary using:

```
data$C_SEVR <- ifelse(data$C_SEV>1, 1, 0)
```

The main issue is this: Every time I try to run a logistical regression, the coefficients include every single class under that variable.
Ex: After using

```
model <- glm(C_SEVR ~ P_AGE,family=binomial(link='logit'),data=train)
summary(model)
```

I get this:

[image]

I just need each variable and not every category under that variable... not sure what's going on

Any help would be greatly appreaciated.

Comment: you can use `dput` to share your dataset in a reproducible way

Comment: also `P_AGE` is missing from screenshot of your data. It is likely to be a factor, which you need to transform to be a number, eg. try `as.integer`.

Comment: I was going to say the same thing @Bullat said. Make sure P_AGE is a numeric variable.

Comment: the dataset is quite large so dput doesn't seem to be feasible. The dataset is here: https://open.canada.ca/data/en/dataset/1eb9eba7-71d1-4b30-9fb1-30cbdab7e63a . I tried using as.integer but the same output occurs. Getting quite frustrated haha

Comment: Most likely p_age is a factor, to convert try as.integer(as.character( )).  If you try going from factor the variable will just be numbered from 1 to n